# Compilation LaTeX to Word

Tags: pdftex, latex-to-word

Is there any way to compilte a `*.tex` file to word instead of pdf?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Why would anybody want to do that? I'm not aware of any, but I think word has a feature to read pdfs.

Comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latex-to-word